# How to use Android Studio Profiler to view Images allocated

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks, memory-profiling

I'm doing some memory profiling on an application and am trying to dig into where some of my memory bloat is coming from.

After running my profiler for about 30 seconds I can see that my shallow size is 237,716,272 bytes (237 MB).

If I sort the heap by type I find that byte[] is guilty for 234,214,768 bytes of my allocations or a whopping 98.52% of the memory profiled.

I entered the instance view and can see that the top 10 `byte[]` allocations are all going through

```
createBitmap:977, Bitmap (android.graphics)
```

So these `byte[]` are clearly images. Size of them is as follows

- 11,137,024
- 11,128,832
- 9,592,832
- 9,592,832
- 9,592,832
- 9,592,832
- 9,592,832
- 9,592,832
- 9,592,832

Now my application has a couple big fullscreen images, so the first two allocations make perfect sense. What doesn't make sense is what comes after, which is an object of size 9,592,832 repeated 22 times... or 211 MB of data. Is there a way to crack the byte[] open from the memory profiler and see what is in some of these identically sized objects? Clearly the gains of eliminating some of them would drastically improve the memory of my allocation. Any other tips or suggestions are appreciated, I'm knew to AndroidStudio and its tooling and am still digging through documentation and learning the ropes.

Thanks!